# Is there a way to convert these symbols to plain text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I've got several records in my database that look like these:

```
ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑÐµÐ¹
æŒ¯å®‡
```

Is there a mysql query I can run to select a more plaintext version of these and others?

Comment: What language are these records (just to know if I have success if I play around with your problem)?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it like this:

```
CAST('ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑÐµÐ¹' AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)
```

Comment: `select CAST('ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑÐµÐ¹' AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)`        output: `ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑÐµÐ¹`

Comment: That's what I got as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Try using Cast and Convert function.
Although, it does not a good solution to waste overhead of character set conversion on every query.

You should convert (or migration) the table charset into your preference language or UTF something.

Comment: We're migrating out of the database entirely. Also, I realize that there is likely a solution related to CAST or CONVERT but nothing I have tried with those works. Do you know what might?

Comment: @eisaacson did you know the correct form plain text ?
I think the strange character is just a form of character encoding
if you compare between binary of correct form and strange form, is it the same ?

Comment: I do not know what the example is supposed to be. I have a lot of similar characters in my database. I want to be able to convert them all.